# Trying to highlight a substring with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write a JS function which will, within an element (a td), find a substring, and highlight it. It only needs to work for the first occurrence of the substring within the element. I am just trying to highlight some keywords on my blog.

Here is what I have tried so far -

JavaScript

```
function highlight(s, search) {
    return s.replace(new RegExp(
        search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'gi'
    ), '<b>$&</b>');
}
```

*Note the object['highlight'] is an object I have access to in my Ruby on Rails code.*

HTML

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>...</th>  
      </tr>       
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="test">This element contains text to be highlighted</td>
        <script>highlight($('test').html(), <% object['highlight'].first %>)</script>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I try to run this code, nothing is highlighted.

Can anyone see what I have done incorrectly here ?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention that you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/). It can highlight keywords/terms or custom regular expressions. It is also available as jQuery plugin.

**DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mt1j5tjd/)**

```js
var context = document.querySelector(".test");
var instance = new Mark(context);
// "text" is '<% object['highlight'].first %>'
instance.mark("text");
```

```css
mark{
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>...</th>  
      </tr>       
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="test">This element contains text to be highlighted</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julmot/mark.js/6.1.0/dist/mark.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to append the text back on to the td.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>  
    </tr>       
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="test">
        This element contains text to be highlighted
        <script>highlight('.test', '<%= object['highlight'].first %>')</script>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript part

```
<script>
  function highlight(s, search) {
    text = $(s).html();
    modifiedText = s.replace(new RegExp(
        search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'gi'
    ), '<b>$&</b>');
    $(s).html(modifiedText);
}
</script>
```

Edit:

Even though this might answer the OP's question, this is **not recommended**. It would be better to use any libraries like [this](https://github.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex) or [this](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It now finds the text, but replaces it with "test"! Any ideas?

Comment: Okay. There was some error in the erb part in the html. I've updated the answer. (I am guessing your javascript replace part is correct. If you are not sure, you can refer this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FutureWebDev/HfS7e/

Comment: Note that using `.html()` (jQuery) or `innerHTML` (VanillaJS) will remove events inside the element and generates the DOM again and again. It is evil, you should avoid making it that way.

Comment: Yeah this is not the right way to do this. I'd also suggest going with julmot's answer.